# how to add require_once into dompdf document

Tags: php, dompdf

I am editing a dompdf php file, that renders a page i have auto-generated into a pdf document.  I am trying to set a static header/footer on each page, via the php command :

```
<?php require_once 'header.php';?>
<?php require_once 'footer.php';?>
```

For some odd reason, the dompdf renderer is not accepting this, and I have not been able to find out in the documentation how to change this to make it work.  Does anyone have any input of how I can do this?

Comment: not enough code to be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you put this code in your source document that you are loading into dompdf?

For versions of dompdf prior to 0.6.1 you have to ensure that the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` configuration constant is set to true for dompdf to do any PHP processing of standard PHP (`<?php ... ?>`) or embedded scripts (`<script type="text/php">...</script>`).

Starting with version 0.6.1 dompdf will no longer render standard PHP contained in the HTML document but it still supports embedded script.

Best practice if you want to use PHP to generate HTML content is to pre-render the document before loading it into dompdf. You can either do this using output buffering (`ob_start(); /*some PHP to generate your HTML*/; var $html = ob_get_clean(); ob_end_clean();`) or by accessing the document via your web server via URL with protocol and domain.

Comment: Thanks Brian - that was precisely what I was looking for!